# vCard 4.0 Regex

Tags: c#, regex, vcf-vcard

a while ago, I created a program to process vCard files. This could be done virtually perfectly with the following:

```
(?<FIELD>[^\s:;]+)(;(?<PARAM>[^:]+))*:(?<CONTENT>.*(?>\r\n[ \t].*)*)$
```

However, this doesn't work for the new (August 2011) vCard 4.0 standard. The problem is that vCard 4.0 files use the following layout:

```
FIELD(:)(;([PARAMETER]="[CONTENT],[MORE CONTENT]"(;))[DATATYPE(:)]:)CONTENT[newline]
```

e.g.

```
ADR;type="home,work":(address)
```

As you can see, I would like to capture the whole parameter, including the type="..." stuff.

So my question is: can my code be modified or will I have to write two processes (one for the old types and one for the new 4.0 version; ideally, I would like to support both) and if so, how? (I'm using c# and .net 4.0 by the way).

Regards.

Comment: you seriously should add more info about "your code" that could/could not be modified, to support everything...

Comment: What about this photo field from the vCard 4.0 spec:

`PHOTO:data:image/jpeg;base64,MIICajCCAdOgAwIBAgICBEUwDQYJKoZIhvAQEEBQAwdzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxLDAqBgNVBAoTI05ldHNjYXBlIENvbW11bmljYXRpb25zIENvcnBvcmF0aW9uMRwwGgYDVQQLExNJbmZvcm1hdGlvbiBTeXN0<...remainder of base64-encoded data...>`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex:

```
(?<FIELD>[^\s:;]+)(;(?<PARAM>[^=:;]+)=\"?(?<VALUE>[^:;]+)\"?)*:(?<CONTENT>[^;]*;?)*
```

That query seems to handle both the vCard 3.0 example provided [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard):

```
ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
```

And the 4.0 example:

```
ADR;TYPE=work;LABEL="42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America"
 :;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
```

It also matches this example from the vCard 4.0 Specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350):

```
ADR;GEO="geo:12.3457,78.910";LABEL="Mr. John Q. Public, Esq.\n
      Mail Drop: TNE QB\n123 Main Street\nAny Town, CA  91921-1234\n
      U.S.A.":;;123 Main Street;Any Town;CA;91921-1234;U.S.A.
```

My disclaimer is that I don't have any expertise in vCard specifically, I just skimmed a portion of the spec and looked at examples while playing around with [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) so it's possible that I'm missing some edge cases.